# Create Collaboration Project using GitHub and VSCode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, collaboration

I have to work on a school project in a team and we've decided to use GitHub & VSCode to edit the code. I am a complete Noob in using GitHub & VSCode as I only every coded alone. I created a repository and I have invited my teammate as a collaborator. I also cloned the repo to both our laptops and we both can commit changes, but if I commit a change his VSCode doesn't get refreshed.

I am sorry but could someone explain what options we have? I know that you can pull changes but I wanted both to be on the original repository and pulling seems to give me a error because I pull from and to the same branch.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's the expected behaviour, git has never been designed to automatically make changes in other people's computers. You need to push changes to share them and pull them to have them. That's the basic git workflow explained in every git tutorial. If you're getting error messages when running certain commands, why don't you ask about that? It feels easier than trying to find an alternative to the procedure everyone's using.

Answer (score 1):

> I also cloned the repo to both our laptops

That means your VSCode is linked to the same remote repository.
Since a `git commit` is a *local* action, you need to push.

If you are both working on the same branch, you  will also need to pull in order to fetch and merge changes pushed by your colleague.
You can trigger that through the [Git Status Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_git-status-bar-actions).

Comment: Thank you! I was confused as to how all of that works but that cleared it up!